# x86 code execution after call/return/jmp etc?

Tags: assembly, x86

I hope this question isn't to stupid cause it may seem obvious.
As I'm doing a little research on Buffer overflows I stumble over a simple question:

After going to a new Instruction Address after a call/return/jump:
Will the CPU execute the OP Code at that address and then move one byte to the next address and execute the next OP Code and so on until the next call/return/jump is reached?  Or is there something more tricky involved?

Comment: Nothing tricky. It's that simple (tocayo).

Comment: Well, instructions are longer than one byte, but otherwise that's pretty much how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit boringly extended explanation (saying the same as those comments):

CPU has special purpose register *instruction pointer* `eip`, which points to the next instruction to execute.

A `jmp`, `call`, `ret`, etc. ends internally with something similar to:
`mov eip,<next_instruction_address>`.

While the CPU is processing instructions, it does increment `eip` by appropriate size of last executed instruction **automatically** (unless overridden by one of those `jmp`/`j[condition]`/`call`/`ret`/`int`/... instructions).

Wherever you point the `eip` (by whatever means), CPU will try it's best to execute content of that memory as next instruction opcode(s), not aware of any context (where/why did it come from to this new `eip`). Actually this amnesia sort of happens ahead of each instruction executed (I'm silently ignoring the modern internal x86 architecture with various pre-execution queues and branch predictions, translation into micro instructions, etc... :) ... all of that are implementation details quite hidden from programmer, usually visible only trough poor performance, if you disturb that architecture much by jumping all around mindlessly). So it's CPU, `eip` and **here&now**, not much else.

note: some context on x86 can be provided by defining the memory layout by supervising code (like OS), ie. marking some areas of memory as non-executable. CPU detecting it's `eip` pointing to such area will signal a failure, and fall into "trap" handler (usually managed by OS also, killing the interfering process).

Answer (score 1):

The `call` instruction saves (onto the stack) the address to the instruction after it onto the stack. After that, it simply jumps. It doesn't explicitly tell the cpu to look for a `return` instruction, since that will be handled by popping (from the stack) the return address that `call` saved in the first place. This allows for multiple calls and returns, or to put it simply, *nested calls*.

Comment: This is true, but I think the OP was just asking if execution continues to the next instruction when the instruction isn't a jump.  That's why I downvoted the question as not useful.

Answer (score 0):

> While the CPU is processing instructions, it does increment eip by 
>   appropriate size of last executed instruction automatically (unless 
>   overridden by one of those jmp/j[condition]/call/ret/int/... instructions).

That's what i wanted to know.

I'm well aware that thers more Stuff arround (NX Bit, Pipelining ect).

Thanks everybody for their replys

Comment: It's part of the instruction decoding process (at least to calculate the byte size of the decoded opcode. I have little idea where exactly the `eip+=size;` happens, but it must be really early, as for example `call`/`jmp` contains relative offset which is added to `eip` - already pointing to the instruction after that `call`/`jmp`! So `self: jmp self` is in machine code `EB FE` (<jmp> <-2>).